# Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 Has Experienced an Internal Error, Unity Scope Loader

Tags: unity, error-handling

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 a few weeks ago and everything has been working fine up until today.

I received the following message:

> Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 Has Experienced an Internal Error.

I didn't think much of it and continued working on my computer. Suddenly, the monitor screen just went black. The monitor was on, the computer was on, but the screen was black.

I rebooted and everything has been fine for the most part, though I have received that error message again.

According to the read out, the problem type is a crash and the title is 
unity-scope-loader assert failure:

> Error in /user/bin/unity-scope-loader: free(): invalid pointer:
>   0x0000000000df0c60

No idea what the means.

Answer (score 3):

Upon investigating, it seems that libunity9, which as best as I can tell provides unity-scope-loader, is known to be buggy as shown [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libunity/+bug/1271955), [here](https://bugs.dogfood.paddev.net/ubuntu/+source/libunity/+bugs?field.tag=amd64), and [here](https://wyldeplayground.net/sorry-ubuntu-16-04-has-experienced-an-internal-error-unity-scope-loader/).

I ran across a similar problem today. I continued to incur errors related to this for sometime. I was able to alleviate this issue with a reinstall of `libunity9`.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libunity9
```

After the reinstall and reboot, I haven't received the error message again.